# Retrieving title and despcription from XML using AJAX script

Tags: xml

I'm trying to extract the title and the description elements from a XML file using AJAX but I'm having some issues. I've been able to get every title elements but I can't get description elements that come with them. I've tried to use ChildNode in another for loop but I can't get it to work. Do you know how I could get it to work? Thanks!

Here's my code to retrieve title only :

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ajaxRequest(){
        var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] 
        if (window.ActiveXObject){ 
            for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
                try{
                    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
                }
                catch(e){
                }
            }
        }
        <!-- else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) -->
        return new XMLHttpRequest()
        <!-- else -->
        return false
        }

    var mygetrequest = new ajaxRequest()
    if (mygetrequest.overrideMimeType)
        mygetrequest.overrideMimeType('text/xml')
    mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
            if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
                var xmldata=mygetrequest.responseXML 
                var rssentries=xmldata.getElementsByTagName("item")
                var output='<ul>'
                for (var i=0; i<rssentries.length; i++){
                    output+='<li>'
                    output+='<a href="'+rssentries[i].getElementsByTagName('link')                    [0].firstChild.nodeValue+'">'
                    output+=rssentries[i].getElementsByTagName('title')    [0].firstChild.nodeValue+'</a>'
                    output+='</li>'
                }
                output+='</ul>'
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=output
            }
            else{
                alert("Error")
            }
        }
    }
    mygetrequest.open("GET", "testfile.xml", true) 
    mygetrequest.send(null)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [`selectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) available, and assuimg you want to get `<description>` node under `<item>` node, then try something like this :

```
var description = rssentries[i].selectSingleNode('.//description');
```

The question isn't very clear as posted. Posting sample XML and pointing out which node exactly you're having trouble to get should be able to clear things up.